# Delay dialog pop up (setTimeout)

Tags: javascript

I have a dialog box at the bottom of the window that pops up after the user clicks an opener. I want the dialog box to automatically pop up after say 10 seconds if the user hasn't already opened it. Can anyone please help me add the setTimeout code to my JS? Thanks.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false,
    draggable: false,
    height: "170",
    width: "150",
 title: false,
 show: {effect: 'slide', direction: 'down', speed: 1000},
    hide: {effect: 'slide', direction: 'down', speed: 1000},
    resizable: false,
    position: { my: "right bottom", at: "right bottom", of: window },
    create: function (event) { $(event.target).parent().css('position', 'fixed');},
    open: function() {
   
    }
});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` then clear it if the user opens the dialog manually.  If you don't clear it, the dialog could be opened twice (once from the user, then again from the `setTimeout`)

```
var openAuto = setTimeout(function () {
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
}, 10000);

$("#opener").click(function() {
  clearTimeout(openAuto);
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: Mike, is it now possible to add time restrictions on this pop up, so it only appears between 9am and 5pm? Thanks